# Why email address and domain address for developers in AD?

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

Every developer in my company has one email address. eg: Name@country.domain.com

But they also have a domain address/name Name@country.domain.net(hereby refereed as DN)

This is causing a lot of confusion

1. One is used as email(.com) while the other is not, even-though they both look like emails
2. Some applications use DN to provide access, some applications use email address to provide access
3. Some developers country changed, they decided not to change the email which was okay for network admin. But the DN had to be changed to the correct country they are in. Why is it mandatory for domain address to change the country while email can remain as it is?
4. Due to the last problem #3, we had to find the applications that use DN and update them all.

Here are some more questions:

1. Why this is email address and then a DN, why cant there be only one?
2. What exactly is the purpose of DN?
3. Does every user need to have this(or just developers)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The abbreviation "DN" refers to the [`distinguishedName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-distinguishedname) attribute in AD. It also uniquely identifies the account, but it is not what you're talking about here.

What you're talking about is the [`userPrincipalName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-userprincipalname) attribute (or UPN). It is usually the "username" (`sAMAccountName` attribute) followed by `@` and the DNS domain name of the AD domain. It sounds like that is how your organization is setup. Since the accounts moved domains, the domain portion of the UPN needs to change.

However, technically, the UPN suffix (the domain portion) can be anything, especially any domain that your organization controls. It could even be set the same as the email address, it just doesn't have to be.

So if the UPN in your organization does not match the email address, then either your admins just haven't put the effort into making that happen, or they have a reason for not doing so.

You cannot authenticate to AD directly with an email address. If an application just asks for an email and password and using that to authenticate against AD, then it would have to look up that email address on the domain to find the username and then use the username (either `sAMAccountName` or `userPrincipalName`) to authenticate.

There is some more reading here that might help: [User Naming Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/naming-properties)

Comment: in the link provided it states "The point of the UPN is to consolidate the email and logon namespaces so that the user only needs to remember a single name." , yes ..yes

Comment: Yeah, it's certainly ideal for the UPN to match the email, but it's kind of silly that it's not *required*.